# Enlarge the image to fullscreen when clicking on the recyclerView item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Before you mark it as duplicate. Please read.

I am building a chat app. I am receiving the messages(both text and images) in a recyclerView and I have a typical Adapter Class.

Now I want whenever I click o the image it should enlarge to the fullscreen. I have seen solution to this situation but they didn't get me anywhere. Some said opening another activity and passing the URL but then the image is downloaded twice.

Any help will be appreciated. Just the approarch will be fine if not the code. Thanks.

Below is part of my adapter class:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    switch (holder.getItemViewType()){
        case 1:
            ViewHolder1 viewHolder1 = (ViewHolder1)holder;
            viewHolder1.Text.setText(messageList.get(position).getMessage());
            break;

        case 2:
            ViewHolder2 viewHolder2 = (ViewHolder2)holder;
            Glide.with(viewHolder2.Image.getContext())
                    .load(messageList.get(position).getMessage())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_image_send_24dp)
                    .crossFade()
                    .centerCrop()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(viewHolder2.Image);

            viewHolder2.Image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent= new Intent(context,FullScreenImage.class);
                    intent.putExtra("image_url", messageList.get(position).getMessage());
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: downloaded twice? with `diskCacheStrategy`?

Comment: If I pass the URL from one activity to another and then use that URL in the glide it will be downloaded again right? Although from the next time onward it wont download again.

Comment: imho, it will download once, later on the cache will be used

Comment: Updated my code. Passing the image URL to `FullScreenImage.class`. So when I am offline the image in the `FullScreenImage activity` wont load.

Comment: see https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-caching-basics and https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-how-to-choose-the-best-caching-preference

Comment: My bad. You were right. I missed `diskCacheStrategy` in the other class. Now I feel like I should not have posted this. But lets say it will help others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this works then:

In Adapter Class:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    switch (holder.getItemViewType()){
        case 1:
            ViewHolder1 viewHolder1 = (ViewHolder1)holder;
            viewHolder1.Text.setText(messageList.get(position).getMessage());
            break;

        case 2:
            ViewHolder2 viewHolder2 = (ViewHolder2)holder;
            Glide.with(viewHolder2.Image.getContext())
                    .load(messageList.get(position).getMessage())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_image_send_24dp)
                    .crossFade()
                    .centerCrop()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(viewHolder2.Image);

            viewHolder2.Image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent= new Intent(context,FullScreenImage.class);
                    intent.putExtra("image_url", messageList.get(position).getMessage());
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            break;
    }
}
```

And then in new Activity:

```
    public class FullScreenImage extends AppCompatActivity {


    ImageView myImage;
    String url = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_screen_image);

        url = getIntent().getStringExtra("image_url");

        myImage = findViewById(R.id.myImage);
        Glide.with(this).load(url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_image_send_24dp)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_image_send_24dp)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(myImage);
    }
}
```